# Combine normal form with file inputs with dropzone

Tags: javascript, file-upload, dropzone.js

I've a problem with combining "normal" form with dropzone. I've got a form with text inputs, file inputs and dropzone section. And I want post everything at once. So I'm creating dropzone field manually, I'm disabling `autoProcessQueue` feature of dropzone and binding to `onClick` of submit button.

```
<form action="/Exhibits/Create" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="newExhibitForm" method="post">
    <input id="Exhibit_Name" name="Exhibit.Name" type="text"
    <input id="Exhibit_Description" name="Exhibit.Description" type="text">

    <input id="ModelFile" name="ModelFile" type="file">
    <input id="TextureFile" name="TextureFile" type="file">

    <div id="dropzonePreview" class="dropzone-previews form-control dz-clickable">
        <div class="dz-message">Drag&drop</div>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default">
</form>
```

JS part:

```
var photoDropzone = new Dropzone("#newExhibitForm", {
    url: $('#newExhibitForm').attr("action"),
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 10,
    maxFiles: 10,
    previewsContainer: '#dropzonePreview',
    clickable: '#dropzonePreview',

    // The setting up of the dropzone
    init: function () {
        var myDropzone = this;

        var submitButton = document.querySelector('input[type=submit]');
        myDropzone = this; // closure

        submitButton.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            if (myDropzone.getQueuedFiles().length === 0) {
                $('#newExhibitForm').submit();
            }
            else {
                myDropzone.processQueue();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

And when I submit my form by clicking submit button, in the server-side function there are dropzone files, text inputs, but file inputs aren't send.

Is there a way to make it work in the way I described at the beginning?

Regards,
Konrad

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, but at the time each file gets uploaded individually. So you would need to store the files separately on your server, and then when dropzone emits the `complete` event, you would send the rest of the input fields.